# How to create a mongodb query object using variables in nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb-query

The query works in mongo console : db.blogs.find({title : /fun/i});
but I tried to use it in nodejs, it won't work if I do it as :

```
var keyword = "fun";

query = { "title" : "/"+keyword+"/i" }; //doesn't work

query = { "title" : /fun/i };  //works, but I need to use the variable name - keyword
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When dynamically creating a regular expression, you need to use the `RegExp` constructor instead of the literal notation with the `/`chars:

```
var keyword = "fun";
var query = {title: new RegExp(keyword, "i")};
```